# Datascraping to add to my existing offline dataframe with xml2 in R

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, xml2

I am trying to scrape data from the IGRF Magnetic Model Calculator (https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml#igrfgrid) into a data frame that I already have that contains dates and lat/long. I only need two values from the calculator: total intensity and inclination.

My data frame looks like this (2012-2022; 24,000 observations):

| UID | Animal ID | YEAR | Latitude | Longitude | Intensity | Inclination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C678 | 2012 | 30.98763 | -80.98457 | [add] | [add] |
| 2 | C679 | 2013 | 29.89765 | -82.38304 | [add] | [add] |

Right now, I have my code running in a For loop to append these values to a list, but I am stuck on two main problems:

1. I would like this data to add to a new column to my data frame called “Intensity  and “Inclination” so that is paired with my other observational data rather than in an empty list.
2. I am running into time out issues. The data frame I have has 20 columns and 24,000 rows, but my for loop stops running around entry 2,500. Is there a more efficient way to run this computation? (w/o a for-loop)

My code currently  looks like this:

```
DF <- DF[which(!is.na(DF$Latitude) & !is.na(DF$Longitude)),]
Inclination<-list()
Intensity<-list()
base_url = "https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateIgrfwmm?"
for (i in 1:length(DF$UID)) {

full_url= paste0(base_url, "lat1=", DF$Latitude[i],
         "&lon1=",DF$Longitude[i], "&model=IGRF", "&startYear=", DF$Year[i], "&endYear=", DF$Year[i], "&key=EAU2y&resultFormat=xml")

dat <- read_xml(full_url)
xml_structure(dat) #how the xml is structured

dates <- as.numeric(xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, xpath = "//date")))
longs <- as.numeric(xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, xpath = "//longitude")))
lats <- as.numeric(xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, xpath = "//latitude")))
intensity_val <- as.numeric(xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, xpath = "//totalintensity")))
inclination_val <- as.numeric(xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, xpath = "//inclination")))

Intensity<-append(Intensity,intensity_val)
Inclination<-append(Inclination,inclination_val)

}
```

Comment: Your 2nd issue is mot likely caused by not limiting request rate. https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/help/igrfgridHelp.html :  */../A maximum of 50 connections/second from all the users is allowed at any time. If this is exceeded, the back-end calculator stops taking requests for 10 seconds. Bulk calculations should be requested serially and not in parallel. If the requests start returning with errors then your script should go to sleep for 5-10 minutes before trying the next request/../*

Comment: `base_url` is missing from your code. Maybe the [wmm](https://github.com/wfrierson/wmm) package provides what you want.